# Adding trends to a curve plotted from beta regression model

Tags: r, ggplot2, regression, prediction, bayesian

I have the sample dataset and code below and would appreciate your help to add trends to the curve from a beta regression model in order to visualize expect values of `yield` for values of the variable `temp` that are outside the range `200-450`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(betareg)
data("GasolineYield", package = "betareg")
md <- betareg(yield ~ temp, data = GasolineYield,
                 link = "cloglog")

ggplotly(
ggplot(GasolineYield, aes(x = temp, y = yield)) +
geom_point(size = 4, aes(fill = batch), shape = 21) +
geom_line(aes(y = predict(md, GasolineYield)), col="red") +
theme_classic())
```

#### Update

It turned out that I need to use `pred.zoib` instead of `predict` because my data are `zero-and-one inflated`, and simply replacing one by the other does not work and gives this error:

```
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'yield' not found
```

Therefore, I would appreciate any ideas on how to adjust the answer by @Adela to the original question in order to accomplish the same objective but now using [`zoib` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoib/zoib.pdf) instead of [`betareg` package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/betareg/betareg.pdf).

A sample code is given:

```
library(zoib)
re.md <- zoib(yield ~ temp | 1 | 1, data=GasolineYield,
joint = FALSE, random=1, EUID=GasolineYield$batch,
zero.inflation = FALSE, one.inflation = FALSE,
n.iter=3200, n.thin=15, n.burn=200)
```

Comment: I'm not into installing JAGS but I guess that approach with `zoib` would be the same as I described below. Did you try to use my code with `predict.zoib` instead of `predict`?

Comment: it doesn't require JAGS.  Just `install.packages("zoib")` .

Comment: Hi, @Adela. Any idea on where is this error coming from and how can this be addressed? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not able to load `zoib` package without `rjags` because of absence of JAGS. Were you able to run your sample code? And what is the code you used for prediction?

Comment: `rjags` cannot be loaded without JAGS. Try to provide the code for prediction you used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168741/discussion-between-krantz-and-adela).

Comment: @Adela thanks for your great help again. Problem solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to predict new data with values of `temp` outside the range `200-450`.

See my example:

```
# predict with new data
df <- data.frame(yield = predict(md, data.frame(temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01))),
                 temp = seq(100, 600, 0.01))

# plot
ggplotly(
  ggplot() +
    geom_point(data = GasolineYield, 
               aes(x = temp, y = yield, fill = batch),
               size = 4, shape = 21) +
    xlim(100, 600) + 
    geom_line(data = df, aes(y = yield, x = temp), col="red") +
    theme_classic())
```

Comment: Perfect, @Adela. This works! Just a small question, if you don't mind: I would also like to get these plotted predictions as a `data.frame` with two variables `yield` and `temp`.Thanks a lot!

Comment: Happy to hear that! I updated the code. Is now `df` what you need?

Comment: that solves my problem completely. Please accept my deepest gratitude for your tremendous help.